# Is it possible to limit of object creation of a model in admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models

I just want to know that is it possible to limit the number of objects of a model in admin panel?

It is that, for example, I have a model named 'Homepage' and in the admin panel I don't want a user can create more than one instance of Homepage.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's just the admin that you want to affect (and don't want to affect the database model), you can create a custom ModelAdmin subclass:

```
class HomePageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def add_view(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            # Assuming you want a single, global HomePage object
            if HomePage.objects.count() > 1:
                # redirect to a page saying 
                # you can't create more than one
                return HttpResponseRedirect("foo")
        return super(HomePageAdmin, self).add_view(request)

# ...

admin.site.register(HomePage, HomePageAdmin)
```

An alternative strategy to do the same thing is to create a custom ModelForm for HomePage, with a `clean` method that enforces the single HomePage requirement. This will make your requirement appear as a validation error, rather than as a redirect (or as a database error):

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.util import ErrorList

class HomePageModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        if HomePage.objects.count() > 1:
            self._errors.setdefault('__all__', ErrorList()).append("You can only create one HomePage object.")
        return self.cleaned_data

# ...
class HomePageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = HomePageModelForm

# ...

admin.site.register(HomePage, HomePageAdmin)
```

If it's "one HomePage per user", you will need HomePage to have a ForeignKey to User and adapt the above.  You may also need to store the current User object in threadlocals in order to access it from `HomePageModelForm.clean`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit `Homepage` to one for every user, then you could use one-to-one relation, with [`OneToOneField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield). As for limiting to N - a [`pre_save` signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#topics-signals) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class HomePage(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
  homepage = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = (("user", "homepage"),)
```